# Type or namespace FtpWebRequest could not be found in MonoDevelop

Tags: c#, .net, monodevelop, ftpwebrequest, system.net

I have a C# Windows Forms application on MonoDevelop. I want to upload and download files to an FTP location. While trying to use `FtpWebRequest`, I get compile error:

> "type or namespace could not be found. Are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly"

I have used System.Net and System.IO and also referenced them. I am using .Net 4.0 as target framework. What am I missing?

Comment: yes, I have: using System.Net; using System.IO

Comment: what version of mono?

Comment: MonoDevelop 2.8.8.4, Mono 2.10.8